# In C#, how to parse json which has a string containing a comma

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I am using the `DataContractJsonSerializer` in C# and I am trying to deserialize the below Json array, how ever it is failing because the `"PlaceName"` string value contains a comma.

Error message:

> XmlException: The value 'Chicago, IL' cannot be parsed as the type 'Int32'.

```cs
[{\"PlaceId\":343,\"PlaceName\":\"Chicago, IL\"},{\"PlaceId\":345,\"PlaceName\":\"New York, NY\"}]
```

This is the function I am using.

deserializeJSON function

```cs
static public T deserializeJSON<T>(string json)
{
    var instance = typeof(T);

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(instance);
        return (T)deserializer.ReadObject(ms);
    }
}
```

```cs
string json = "[{\"PlaceId\":343,\"PlaceName\":\"Chicago, IL\"},{\"PlaceId\":345,\"PlaceName\":\"New York, NY\"}]"
List<Places> places = new List<Places>();

places = Common.deserializeJSON<List<Places>>(json);
```

Class

```cs
public class Places
{
    public int PlaceId { get; set; }
    public int PlaceName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `XmlException` you say, when parsing json?

Comment: Even without the comma, I highly doubt the value `"Chicago"` could be parsed as an integer either...

Comment: Ah Chicago, my favorite integer

Comment: `DataContractSerializer` was based on XML. When they created the `DataContractJsonSerializer` they probably forgot to update the error messages.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem has nothing to do with the comma, but with the class you provided. `PlaceName` should be a `string`, not `int`.

Comment: Hello Blindy, thank you so much, I missed that.  Ugh